# Jython printing all terminal output / assign output as string

Tags: java, python, jython

Iv been looking into embedding jython into my java program to allow users to script in python. However i want to print the output of their python scripts into a java text box in my program. But i cannot find a way to embed the output of the jython engine:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

    public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
        ScriptEngine pyEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("python");
        Object Pyoutput = pyEngine.eval("2*3");
        System.out.println(Pyoutput.toString());
      }
    }
```

I tried this to get the output of eval.

```
This outputs 6
```

Which is correct however when i try the same from a print statement:

```
Object Pyoutput = pyEngine.eval("print('Hello World')");
System.out.println(Pyoutput.toString());
```

the output is null when it should be Hello World. Is there a way to print the entire output/terminal content of a script that has been eval/exec by jython?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a [`Writer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) for the scripts to use through the engines [`ScriptContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptContext.html). For example:

```
ScriptEngine pyEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("python");
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
pyEngine.getContext().setWriter(sw);
pyEngine.eval("print('Hello World')");
System.out.println(sw.toString());
```

Prints

```
Hello World
```

Comment: Perfect! thanks so much i spent a long time on google looking for how to do this with the only results being to implement various types of stream readers, so thanks again :)